# Angular4 не видит файлы с сервера NET Core

Tags: javascript, angular2, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Делаю апку на  angular4 + net core сервер. Пробую натянуть тему и столкнулся с трудностями. При старте в консоль вилетает :  (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading ко многим js файлам. Когда я создавал апку с нуля таких проблем не было.Возможно кто-то сталкивался с таким?

```
    /**
     * System configuration for Angular samples
     * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
     */
    (function (global) {
      System.config({
        paths: {
          // paths serve as alias
          'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
          // our app is within the app folder
          'app': 'app',

          // angular bundles
          '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
          '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
          '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
          '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
          '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
          '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
          '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
          '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

          // other libraries
          'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
          'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {          
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            meta: {
              './*.js': {
                loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
              }
            }
          },
          rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
    })(this)









    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Energy Brain</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       

        <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
        <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
          <script>
            System.import('app/main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
          </script>
      </head>

      <body>
          <app-root>loading...</app-root>
      </body>
    </html>







    systemjs-angular-loader

    var templateUrlRegex = /templateUrl\s*:(\s*['"`](.*?)['"`]\s*)/gm;
    var stylesRegex = /styleUrls *:(\s*\[[^\]]*?\])/g;
    var stringRegex = /(['`"])((?:[^\\]\\\1|.)*?)\1/g;

    module.exports.translate = function (load) {
        if (load.source.indexOf('moduleId') != -1) return load;

        var url = document.createElement('a');
        url.href = load.address;

        var basePathParts = url.pathname.split('/');

        basePathParts.pop();
        var basePath = basePathParts.join('/');

        var baseHref = document.createElement('a');
        baseHref.href = this.baseURL;
        baseHref = baseHref.pathname;

        if (!baseHref.startsWith('/base/')) { // it is not karma
            basePath = basePath.replace(baseHref, '');
        }

        load.source = load.source
            .replace(templateUrlRegex, function (match, quote, url) {
                var resolvedUrl = url;

                if (url.startsWith('.')) {
                    resolvedUrl = basePath + url.substr(1);
                }

                return 'templateUrl: "' + resolvedUrl + '"';
            })
            .replace(stylesRegex, function (match, relativeUrls) {
                var urls = [];

                while ((match = stringRegex.exec(relativeUrls)) !== null) {
                    if (match[2].startsWith('.')) {
                        urls.push('"' + basePath + match[2].substr(1) + '"');
                    } else {
                        urls.push('"' + match[2] + '"');
                    }
                }

                return "styleUrls: [" + urls.join(', ') + "]";
            });

        return load;
    };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется, что выкладывание node_modules для доступа - не очень хорошая идея. Вообще лично я использую Angular Cli в нем интернация с .Net Core происходит довольно легко, достаточно в angular-cli.json указать путь до wwwroot вашего Asp.Net Core проекта

Comment: Вы могли бы описать процесс интеграции?

Comment: Написал ответом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 4 Cli + ASP.NET Core пошагово.

Создаем папку с проектом например MyProject, далее все через командную строку
Переходим в MyProject

```
cd MyProject
```

Устанавливаем Angular Cli глобально

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Создаем новый проект Angular, назовем его Client

```
ng new Client
```

Переходим в созданный проект

```
cd client
```

Запускаем и проверяем, что проект собирается и запускается (обычно localhost:4200)

```
ng serve
```

После проверки останавливаем, жмем

```
CTRL+C
```

Переходим обратно в MyProject

```
cd ../
```

Создаем проект ASP.NET Web Api, Назовем его Server

```
dotnet new webapi -n Server
```

Теперь, когда у нас создан Server, снова переходим в Client

```
cd client
```

Находим файл .angular-cli.json и изменяем OutDir

```
"outDir": "../Server/wwwroot"
```

Собираем наш Client

```
ng build
```

Теперь все что нужно клиенту лежит в wwwroot. Переходим в Server

```
cd ../Server
```

Дальше работать с проектом можно уже через Visual Studio
Открываем проект и устанавливаем NuGet пакет (версии могут отличаться)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles -Version 2.0.0
```

В папке Controllers cоздаем контроллер чтобы отдавать наш index.html, назовем его HomeController.cs

```
namespace Server.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Spa()
        {
            return File("~/index.html", "text/html");
        }
    }
}
```

В Startup.cs метод Configure добавляем маршруты для работы с SPA и с API

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
     routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}");

     routes.MapRoute("Spa", "{*url}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Spa" });
});
```

Запускаем проект и проверяем

Comment: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

Comment: А как работать с этим? В студии не видит ангуляровских папок.

Comment: Я обычно для Angular использую Visual Studio Code и работаю с ним отдельно, проверяю все через ng serve. А после у меня уже есть готовый клиент в wwwroot. То есть по сути у нас два отдельных проекта, Client и Server

Comment: Попробуйте без lastest
$ npm remove -g angular-cli
$ npm install -g @angular/cli

поправлю в ответе

Comment: Да я так и работаю в 2 студии.