# ASP.NET Core + Angular из существующего проекта

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net, asp.net-core, angular

Имеется готовый фронтэнд на Angular 5, необходимо создать бэкэнд, используя ASP.NET Core 2.1.

Вопрос: как наиболее лёгким и правильным образом перенести фронтэнд часть внутрь ASP.NET Core?

Пытался использовать `dotnet new angular`, но создаваемый шаблон уже имеет свой файл `package.json`, в котором используется Angular версии 4. Можно ли полностью скопировать свой `package.json` вместо этого стандартного? + для переноса модулей в папку ClientApp их необходимо вручную копировать и исправлять пути?

Может быть существует какой-либо другой подход?

Comment: Вы можете создать проект web api настроить для SPA более подробно я описывал тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719710/angular4-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-net-core/721086#721086 так как часть с Angular у вас уже есть, ее можно пропустить

Comment: а зачем вам проект фронтенда внутри проекта бекенда?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну, как минимум, чтоб доставить конечному пользователю контент сайта. А ещё чтоб добавить API

Comment: @B.Vandyshev Но ведь в этом случае не будет работать Hot Module Replacement

Comment: В общем, хочу сделать как в шаблоне `dotnet new angular`, но чтоб с моим контентом, вместо стандартного. Это возможно ведь?..

Comment: @user230288, зачем вам Hot Module Replacement на продакшине? Делаете фронт отдельно, бэк отдельно.

Comment: Вы можете разрабатывать фронт и бек как отдельные проекты, а потом на сервера деплоить сначала бекенд, потом на него в папку wwwroot фронтенд